# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > java.io.IOException: File format error reading

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have a new android project in androidsutio and it gradle successfully without any problems. I do nothing after that, but when I run this project something goes wrong, and give some hints as follow:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   java.io.IOException: File format error reading G:\Android\studioworkspace\MyTestDemo1\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt line 1394: '??my}??uS?*?\?[m?????V=?    U???m?????:???j?t?h=?>??Mc^??4??O????n????|U?bgN-??T??-5f$ygl?l-BH?R?/J??S?V?N?m????'?j???'

This problem also happens when I import other studio project,which can run on other computer by using androidstudio without problems, and I rebuild and clean project, don't work.

Comment: did you find the answer

Comment: Perhaps the answer can be found in this earlier thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/35674066/